# Скрипт периодической съемки с USB камеры

Tags: скрипт, камера, linux

Здравствуйте!

Посоветовали тут спросить. Прошу помощи в маленькой автоматизации. Я вообще не программер (может быть пока)). Есть такая задача - с периодичностью 10 минут делать фотку с usb web камеры, например сохранять в папку /home/vasya/cam с именем "время".jpg, выгружать эту фотку на FTP сервер по ip на порт 2103.

Раньше я сам делал простенькие батники для виндовса. Недавно попробовал по тому же принципу написать типа "командный" файл для Ubuntu - перечисление команд которые набираются в терминале, после каждой команды энтер. Этот файл работал - установка программулины, замена конфига заранее заготовленным. Потом в ручную добавление этой программулины в автозапуск. Но это одноразовый файл + ручная оконцовка + сам файл тупо вручную запускается (банально решение рутины с набором команд в терминале)). Да и навеное корявый это способ.

По опыту предполагаю: сделать файл(или скрипт), который отчищает содержимое папки /home/vasya/cam, делает фотку и сохраняет ее в эту папку с нужным именем, посылает содержимое этой папки на сервер. Добавить выполнение этого файла в какой-нибудь планировщик с периодичностью в 10-30 минут.

Проверять успешность отправки не критично, но былоб приятно (если кто подскажет).
Т.е. на самом компе фотки хранить не надо + это упрощает отбор файла для отправки.
Мне кажется задача простая, просто я в скриптовании для Ubuntu совсем броня. А - на компе Ubuntu 10.04 - 10.10 - думаю там разницы нет особой.

Кто напишет содержание такого файла и как его добавить на запуск с периодичностью - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @Vlad5421, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: man 8 cron, man 1 crontab, man 5 crontab и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы реализовал это на с++ , используя OpenCV - для получения снимка с вебкамеры и "сохранения" его в файл на жесткий диск , и curl для отсылки картинки на ftp сервер.

Достаточно легко найти примеры по c++ и opencv http://robocraft.ru/page/opencv/  и c++ и curl http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html , вам останется только соеденить их воедино , также добавить пару переменных что бы следить за прошедшим временем , а также посмотреть как под Линуксом , "засыпать" программу на пару миллесекунд , что бы оставить процессорное время другим программам, в curl и проверка есть загрузился ли файл на ftp или нет.

Либо использовать связку image magic + консольный curl для ftp , и повесить это дело на cron.